# How to initialize ag-grid api in angular2 application

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am working on an application built using angular2 with typescript.
I am using ag-grid to display data in grid but not able to find the grid api.

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />


import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Hero, HeroService}   from './hero.service';
var gridOptions;
var heroService;
import * as core from 'angular2/core';
declare var ag: any;
ag.grid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular2({ core: core });
@Component({
    selector: 'gridapp',
    template: `<ag-grid-ng2 #gapp class="ag-fresh" style="height: 300px; width:850px" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [rowData]="rowData" enableSorting="true" enableColResize="true" enableFilter="true"></ag-grid-ng2>`,
    directives: [(<any>window).ag.grid.AgGridNg2],
    providers: [HeroService]
})
export class GridViewComponent {

    private columnDefs: Object[];
    private rowData: Object[];



    constructor(private _heroService: HeroService) {
        console.log("in Grid constructor...");
        heroService = this._heroService;
        this.columnDefs = [
            { headerName: "ID", field: "id", sortingOrder: ["asc", "desc"], editable: false, width: 100 },
            { headerName: "Name", field: "name", sortingOrder: ["asc", "desc"], editable: false, hide: false },

        ];

        heroService.getHeroes()
                .then(heroes =>
                    this.rowData = heroes
        );

        gridOptions = {
            enableSorting: true,
            rowData: this.rowData,
            columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
            onReady: function() {
                gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
                alert(gridOptions.api);
            }

        }


    }


}
```

Now when I am trying to execute any method of this.gridOptions.api it is throwing error that "gridOptions.api is undefined. Examples mentioned on ag-grid [site](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-api/index.php) are not working for typescript and angular2.

How can I initialize and use gridApi in angular2 with typescript?

Comment: Have you considered PrimeNG DataTable? It is a native component for Angular2. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to initialize `gridOptions` as a property of the class, not just a variable. So it should be `this.gridOptions`:

```
constructor(private _heroService: HeroService) {

    console.log("in Grid constructor...");

    this.columnDefs = [
        { headerName: "ID", field: "id", sortingOrder: ["asc", "desc"], editable: false, width: 100 },
        { headerName: "Name", field: "name", sortingOrder: ["asc", "desc"], editable: false, hide: false }
    ];

    this._heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.rowData = heroes);

    this.gridOptions = {
        enableSorting: true,
        rowData: this.rowData,
        columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
        onReady: () => {
            this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
            alert(this.gridOptions.api);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For tricky auto-height out of the box, use `domLayout='autoHeight'` in your template where `<ag grid-ng2 ... domLayout='autoHeight'></ag-grid-ng2>`

Answer (score 4):

The above 'almost' got me there in ang 2 rc1 but I found i needed the Grid Options link in the html as well so

```
<ag-grid-ng2 id="mastergrid" #agGrid style="height: 100%; width:100%" class="ag-fresh"
         [gridOptions]="gridOptions" 
                [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
                [showToolPanel]="showToolPanel" 
                [rowData]="rowData" 
                enableSorting 
                enableRangeSelection:true
                suppressRowClickSelection
                enableFilter  
                toolPanelSuppressValues 
                toolPanelSuppressGroups
                debug="false"
                draggable="false"
                rowHeight="22" 
                rowSelection='multiple'> 
        </ag-grid-ng2>
```

and

```
ngOnInit(){
     this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
        onGridReady: () => {
             this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
         }
     };
 }
```

this worked perfectly and the grid resized as the window moved. Thanks to dfsq as I would not have used the handy onGridReady either :)

Answer (score 0):

In your ts file there is a  **gridOptions** variable declared in class level.
     `var gridOptions;` But you are not assigning any value for it. So it's **undefined**.

Inside the **constructor** you are assigning a value for a **gridOptions** variable which is local to that method.

However the **gridOptions** you have bind with grid is the class level variable which is **undefined**. So you are getting an error. So modify the code like follows.

```
constructor(private _heroService: HeroService) {
    ....
    this.gridOptions = {
        enableSorting: true,
        rowData: this.rowData,
        ....
```